# How to fix nodejs throw err; ^ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is how my output looks like. I have exhausted so many methods from previous similar questions but none of them worked in my case. I am really new with node js so any suggestion would be really helpful -

```
C:\Users\pushp\Desktop\factor>snarkjs --help
internal/fs/utils.js:230
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\package.json'
[90m    at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)[39m
[90m    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:35)[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\[4msnarkjs[24m\build\cli.cjs:1228:15)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  errno: [33m-4058[39m,
  syscall: [32m'open'[39m,
  code: [32m'ENOENT'[39m,
  path: [32m'\\C:\\Users\\pushp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\snarkjs\\package.json'[39m
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known bug in the module](https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs/issues/57). You could try patching their code as recommended in the issue, or (what I personally would recommend), get WSL set up so you don't have to fight with as many inconsistencies on Windows. Or you could submit a pull request to that module to fix the issue.