# Snarkjs Error: File not being found even though the file is present in the specified location

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
C:\Users\pushp\Desktop\factor>snarkjs zkey export solidityverifier circuit_final.zkey verifier.sol
[ERROR] snarkJS: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\templates\verifier_groth16.sol'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\C:\\Users\\pushp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\snarkjs\\templates\\verifier_groth16.sol'
}
```

I am getting this error even though I can see the file verifier_groth16.sol in the specified location. What I understand is that my location is `C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\templates\verifier_groth16.sol` whereas I can see an extra `C:\` before the location, which is may be creating the problem. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem, may can help you. I use snarkjs@0.4.6.

```
>snarkjs generateverifier

C:\Users\spike\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\build
\C:\Users\spike\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\build\templates
[ERROR] snarkJS: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\C:\Users\spike\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\templates\verifier_groth16.sol.ejs'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\C:\\Users\\spike\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\snarkjs\\templates\\verifier_groth16.sol.ejs'
}
```

According the github issue#57 （[Can't find package.json in directory](https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs/issues/57)） calvbore's answer.
I just search "verifier_groth16.sol" in C:\Users\spike\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\snarkjs\build\cli.cjs

update line

```
if (await fileExists(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2, "templates"))) {
        templates.groth16 = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2, "templates", "verifier_groth16.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
        templates.plonk = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2, "templates", "verifier_plonk.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
    } else {
        templates.groth16 = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2, "..", "templates", "verifier_groth16.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
        templates.plonk = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2, "..", "templates", "verifier_plonk.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
    }
```

to

```
 if (await fileExists(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2.slice(1,__dirname$1.length), "templates"))) {
    templates.groth16 = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2.slice(1,__dirname$1.length), "templates", "verifier_groth16.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
    templates.plonk = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2.slice(1,__dirname$1.length), "templates", "verifier_plonk.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
} else {
    templates.groth16 = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2.slice(1,__dirname$1.length), "..", "templates", "verifier_groth16.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
    templates.plonk = await fs__default['default'].promises.readFile(path__default['default'].join(__dirname$2.slice(1,__dirname$1.length), "..", "templates", "verifier_plonk.sol.ejs"), "utf8");
}
```

another similar problem is [How to fix nodejs throw err; ^ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723993/how-to-fix-nodejs-throw-err-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open)