# Reduced file size after uploading to S3 bucket from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload files from a particular folder location to a sample S3 bucket. I am using standard nodejs aws-sdk for this. Files are deepzoom images (.dzi) files.
Files are getting uploaded to my S3 bucket but the contents of the file are not getting uploaded properly. Like I am uploading images of sizes 800B, but after uploading the size of image is only 7B. I tried downloading it to see its content but the file doesn't contains the image but just the file name. This is the code I am running for uploading files:

```
function read(file, numFiles) {
fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  const fileContent = Buffer.from(file, "binary");
  s3.putObject(
    {
      Bucket: "sample-bucket",
      Key: file,
      Body: fileContent,
    },
    function (resp) {
      console.log(arguments);
      console.log("Successfully uploaded, ", file);
      uploadCount++;
      console.log("uploadcount is:", uploadCount);
      if (uploadCount == numFiles) {
        res.send("All files uploaded");
      }
    }
  ).on("httpUploadProgress", (evt) => {
    console.log(`Uploaded ${evt.loaded} out of ${evt.total}`);
  });
});
```

}

I am passing files to this read function from another function. I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Before uploading image properties:

[image]

Property of image uploaded to S3 bucket:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Buffer.from(file)` will not return the content of the file but return the buffer of the argument, this time the argument is "file". So the file uploaded to S3 has filename as contents.

Try to change this line

```
const fileContent = Buffer.from(file, "binary");
```

to like this.

```
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, However this solution doesn't work for me. fs library throws error while reading this file.

Comment: I have even tried with file as argument in Body directly, but the result is same.

Comment: Can you share the error message from fs library or any?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723993/how-to-fix-nodejs-throw-err-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open.  Its similar to this error.

Comment: It might be file path issue. If the file is in the same directory with .js, `const file = "xxxx.dzi";`. Path is adjusted using ../  or like that.

Comment: The directory structure is fine. However for some reason it is not able to find .dzi files inside the directory.

Comment: Could it be because I am trying to read .dzi files?

Comment: I've properly uploaded a dzi file... By the way is that possible to upload other extension files?

Comment: I have tried with files of different extensions(.png, .jpg) but I am facing the same issue.

Comment: That's weird. Is the code finding the files properly? Why not starting from simple code like this doc? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-example-creating-buckets-upload-file